# I am getting Xamarin MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2022

I am Debugging Xamarin Application I am getting error Xamarin MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 2.
I am just updated my Visual studio to latest version 17.8.6.

Getting issue while running project in latest visual studio

Comment: I find [a similar thread](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4825) in GitHub about this error.
You can try to enable `Multi-Dex` ( right click your android project folder in VS, select properties. choose Android Options, select Multi-Dex), after that, rebuild & clean (delete all bin\obj manually).

Comment: I have done this still getting same error.

Comment: Are all NuGet packages the latest versions?